# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'

Tags: python, osmnx

Tried to run the method 4 of the example `01-overview-osmnx.ipynb`:

```
# network from address, including only nodes within 1km along the network from the address
G = ox.graph_from_address(
    address="350 5th Ave, New York, NY",
    dist=1000,
    dist_type="network",
    network_type="drive",
)

# you can project the network to UTM (zone calculated automatically)
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
```

but I have this error related to `project_graph`:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [22], line 10
      2 G = ox.graph_from_address(
      3     address="350 5th Ave, New York, NY",
      4     dist=1000,
      5     dist_type="network",
      6     network_type="drive",
      7 )
      9 # you can project the network to UTM (zone calculated automatically)
---> 10 G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osmnx/projection.py:144, in project_graph(G, to_crs)
    141 if "simplified" in G.graph and G.graph["simplified"]:
    142     # if graph has previously been simplified, project the edge geometries
    143     gdf_edges = utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, fill_edge_geometry=True)
--> 144     gdf_edges_proj = project_gdf(gdf_edges, to_crs=gdf_nodes_proj.crs)
    145 else:
    146     # if not, you don't have to project these edges because the nodes
    147     # contain all the spatial data in the graph (unsimplified edges have
    148     # no geometry attributes)
    149     gdf_edges_proj = utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, fill_edge_geometry=False).drop(
    150         columns=["geometry"]
    151     )
...
   5900 ):
   5901     return self[name]
-> 5902 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

However `G.graph['crs']` return:

```
'epsg:4326'
```

where I'm wrong?

**Update**

osmnx was installed as indicated in the installation instruction. However, it seems (at least for my configuration) that with the conda procedure, the `osmnx` version installed is the `1.0.1` instead of `1.2.2` (19th November 2022).
The workaround that worked for me was to install osmnx using pip as the following:

```
conda create -n ox_that_work
conda activate ox_that_work
conda install pip
# install the osmnx requirements (https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/main/requirements.txt)
pip install -r requirements.txt
# install osmnx=1.2.2
pip install osmnx==1.2.2
# install descartes and scikit-learn that aren't listend in the requirements.txt
pip install descartes scikit-learn
```

Comment: What versions of OSMnx, GeoPandas, NetworkX, and Python are you using in this working environment?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine with OSMnx 1.2.2 on Python 3.11 and Python 3.10.

Comment: I realised that the version of osmnx is 1.0.1 (GeoPandas is 0.12.1). However I used the :
`conda config --prepend channels conda-forge`and `conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx`to install osmnx in the ox env. When I run `conda list`I have:
 `osmnx conda-forge/noarch::osmnx-1.0.1-pyhd3deb0d_0 None`

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, did you manage to resolve this?
I have a version of osmnx is 1.0.1 (GeoPandas is 0.12.1) and pyproj 3.4.0. Was the issue in the version of the packages?

Comment: Hi @Lenka, with the update procédure (installing osmnx via pip) did work for me.

Comment: This helped thank you, I was trying to use osmnx along with pandana, which worked in past, but pandana does not like the osmnx set up anymore...I ended up having two environments and doing the first part with osmnx (following your installation), exporting node and edge lists and then importing as a networkx graph into new environment for pandana.