# OSMnx: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, osmnx

This snipped form the documentation leads to the following error

```
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(37.79, 37.78, -122.41, -122.43, network_type='drive')
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
ox.plot_graph(G_projected)
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\utils_geo.py:280: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  for polygon in geometry:
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\utils_geo.py:374: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  for poly in multipoly:
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\utils_geo.py:374: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  for poly in multipoly:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 2
      1 G = ox.graph_from_bbox(37.79, 37.78, -122.41, -122.43, network_type='drive')
----> 2 G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
      3 ox.plot_graph(G_projected)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\projection.py:144, in project_graph(G, to_crs)
    141 if "simplified" in G.graph and G.graph["simplified"]:
    142     # if graph has previously been simplified, project the edge geometries
    143     gdf_edges = utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, fill_edge_geometry=True)
--> 144     gdf_edges_proj = project_gdf(gdf_edges, to_crs=gdf_nodes_proj.crs)
    145 else:
    146     # if not, you don't have to project these edges because the nodes
    147     # contain all the spatial data in the graph (unsimplified edges have
    148     # no geometry attributes)
    149     gdf_edges_proj = utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, fill_edge_geometry=False).drop(
    150         columns=["geometry"]
    151     )

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5902, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5895 if (
   5896     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5897     and name not in self._metadata
   5898     and name not in self._accessors
   5899     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5900 ):
   5901     return self[name]
-> 5902 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

Can anybody help?

I already tried python 3.7 and 3.9. I do not have a clue why this error happens because i used an example from the demo repository. Maybe i did something wrong with the versions?

**Update**

Duplicate of ['DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501770/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-crs)

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74501770/7321942

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are right. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501770/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-crs

Sorry, that I did not found it directly